# How to call in android from code and when call will end it callback to activity, from call is started?

Tags: android

How to call in android from code and when call will end it callback to activity from call is started?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the startActivityForResult-OnActivityResult pattern where you start an activity and when that activity finishes and the user returns to the starting activity, a result is returned with it?